# On PMFs of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, geometric-distribution

**Question**

Consider a sequence of independent trials with probability of success $p$ at each trial. Suppose that $Y$ and $X$ are the times at which the first and second successes happen, respectively.

(a) What are the marginal distributions of $Y$ and $X$?

(b) What is the conditional distribution of $X - y$ given that $Y = y$?

(c) Show that the joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$ is $$p_{X, Y}(x, y) = p^2(1 - p)^{x - 2}\ \forall\ 0 < y < x, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

**My attempt**

(a)

$Y$ is intuitively geometric to me, so its marginal PMF should be $$p(1 - p)^{y - 1}\ \forall\ y \in \mathbb{Z}^+.$$

For $X$ to happen, we must have had $1$ success and $x - 2$ failures first and there are $x - 1$ ways for this to happen, so its marginal PMF should be $$p^2(1 - p)^{x - 2}\ \forall\ x > 1, x \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

(b)

By Bayes' theorem, we have
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(X - y \mid Y = y) & = \frac {\mathbb{P}(X - y, Y = y)} {\mathbb{P}(Y = y)}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac {p(1 - p)^{x - y - 1}} {p(1 - p)^{y - 1}}\\[2 mm]
& = (1 - p)^{x - 2y}
\end{aligned}

(c)

Here, I am only able to use intuition to derive the answer. Since we want the joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$, we see that for $X$ to happen, $Y$ must obviously happen, and so we simply consider how $X$ can happen, that is, we must have $x - 2$ failures and $2$ successes, so the joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$ is $$p_{X, Y}(x, y) = p^2(1 - p)^{x - 2}\ \forall\ 0 < y < x, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

---

Are my answers in parts (a) and (b) correct? In particular, I am skeptical of my answer to part (b) because it does not contain $p$. Where is the probability of my second success then? Moreover, can anyone help with deriving part (c) mathematically and with intuition? Does it involve parts (a) and (b)?

Comment: What does $\mathbb{P}(X - y \mid Y = y)$ mean, according to you? $X-y$ is not an event.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes. I noticed that too, but this is exactly how the question was phrased. I am wondering whether it is a typo and it should be $\mathbb{P}(X - Y \mid Y = y)$ instead?

Comment: Neither of those makes any sense: "$X-y$" and "$X-Y$" are not things that can be true or false, so neither of them has a probability. My best guess is that you mean $\mathbb P(X-y \color{red}{{} = x} \mid Y=y)$, instead. (But you can't apply Bayes' rule to this, because the numerator is the joint PMF, which you do not know until you've solved (c). I think the problem intends you to think about this distribution intuitively: if you know that $Y=y$, what is the distribution of the *remaining* number of trials until $X$?)

Comment: @MishaLavrov hmm, it would be geometric with PMF $p(1 - p)^{x - 1}$?